# How is it possible to wake up the windows phone 8 device?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I need to wake up windows phone 8 device. **App is in foreground and I lock the screen.** 

I tried Toast, but it wakes up **only** when the app is in *background*.
I also tried **Alarms** and **Reminders**. But this button "snooze" is not acceptable for me.
I couldn't find any other way.
Alternatively maybe is it possible to send the app in background programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By waking up you mean unlocking the screen?

You cannot do that. Nor you can resume the app from the background or launch it using any means.

It is simply impossible due to the OS restrictions.

Comment: yes, I actually meant unlocking the screen.Thank you for your quick answer!

Comment: maybe it is possible to switch on the screen? to notify user. so user can unlock the screen himself?

Comment: Nope, only thing you can do is to show the toast notification.